# How to enable Google Calendar API in a Go desktop app (in 2022)?

Tags: go, google-calendar-api

I would like to create a simple console application which can e.g. create an event in Google Calendar, but I cannot use it's API.

Google has a [quick start page](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/go), but the following lines do not work for me:

```
go get google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3
go get golang.org/x/oauth2/google
```

I got the this error:

```
go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
    To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
    like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
    For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
    or run 'go help get' or 'go help install.
```

After checking the website from the error message, I tried to use the `go install` command + the original url, but I could not figure out what version number to use. I tried: @3, @v3, @3.0 etc, but none of them worked, e.g.:

```
 google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3@3: google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3@3: invalid version: unknown revision 3
```

I'm new to Go lang. Has anyone an idea, what should I do at this point?

Comment: You want to use modules. Make sure your local Go environment is set-up as advised by the official docs. Create a project and then you can use the "go get ..." command above. You probably don't need to worry about the @3 version tag. You have "/v3" in there, so that'll use version 3 of the api which should be the latest. More on modules: https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules